# Which version of ECMAScript does Google Apps Scripts support?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I [found a trim function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) I want to use in my Google Apps Script. However, at the bottom of the page, it states that the `trim` function is only supported in ECMAScript 5.

When I go to use it, I notice that it happens to work. However, I'd like to know if it'll work some other way besides needing to test it out. I want to know definitively which version of JavaScript is supported.

Answer (score 0):

ECMAScript 5 is the most commonly supported version of JS. It's pretty safe to use it. But still you can checkout this table to make sure: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/